# Questions on reading the prologue of Aesopus Latinus via LLPSI

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, verbs, poetry, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

> Duplex libelli dos est: quod risum movet
>  et quod prudenti vitam consilio monet.
> Calumniari si quis autem voluerit
>  quod arbores loquantur, non tantum ferae,
> ...
> *(Line 3~6)*

- **Dos** is explained as a dowry by Ørberg: **donum quod alicui debetur (ut marito ab uxore)**.

  - *Dowry* doesn't make sense to me. I checked the dictionary and I found the figurative sense, *gift, endowment*, which I think better for translation.
  - Then why does Ørberg explain it like this?
- Ørberg's note: **prudenti vitam monere = prudentem de vitā monere**.

  - **Prudenti** seems dative here. L&S gives **aliquem de re m.**, **aliquem aliquid m.**, **aliquem alicujus rei m.**, but not **alicui aliquid m.**. Is this an exceptional structure?
- Why is **loquantur** subjunctive? If I'm not mistaken, **quod** means *because* here, and it requires a indicative verb.
- Following is my literal translation:

  - > The gift of the little book is double: because it excites laughter and because it reminds the wise person of life designedly. ...
  - Is this correct?

Comment: Prudenti is ablative, modifying consilio.

Comment: @Kingshorsey That's not what Ørberg thinks.

Comment: *quod prudenti vitam consilio monet* seems to have confused people throughout the ages, if Google Books is any indication. Many think it should be *prudentis*, some think *monet* should be a different word altogether (e.g. *regit*), some think *vita* stands for *homines viventes*, i.e., society or some such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the easy questions first:

- *Dos* does originally mean dowry. But the word over time came to be used to express something like “excellent quality, particular value,” etc. Lewis & Short defines this as “a gift, endowment, talent, property, quality.”
- *Quod* being followed by the subjunctive makes it indirect speech – the speech of those who would criticize the fables; in other words, it indicates the reasons they cite for their rejection of the work. You could translate this as: “If someone should want to cavil at this book on the grounds that trees speak etc.”

Now for the difficult question. The phrase *quod prudenti vitam consilio monet* is dark and has apparently puzzled philologists for centuries. Ørberg offers an explanation, but I am not sure he has solved the riddle.

There seem to be two main schools of thought:

- Those who think that *prudenti* modifies *consilio*, which yields the translation: “that it reminds of life with prudent counsel.” And if we note (from Lewis & Short) that *monere* can also be found “without the accessory notion of reminding or admonishing, in gen., *to teach, instruct, tell, inform, point out*,” we can say: “that it teaches life” (as if as a discipline, I suppose), or “teaches about life.”
- Those who think that *consilio* is has no modifier, believe that *prudenti* describes the recipient of the monition and often emend it to *prudentis*, yielding the translation: “that it teaches the prudent (or: the prudent man) about life with counsel.” Ørberg seems to be in this camp (minus the emendation). In principle you don't need a dictionary to allow the dative to be used – the dative can be used freely to name beneficiaries. Still, *monere* has a normal way of naming the recipient, which is very frequently used, and that's the accusative, so the dative is at least a little unexpected. This interpretation also raises the question why the prudent in particular should need advice. (For a spirited rejection of this objection in Latin, see the [1911 dissertation](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Phaedriana/9glHAQAAIAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA7&printsec=frontcover) by one Alfred H. W. Tacke titled *Phaedriana*).

Of course, *vitam monere* is strange as well. It sounds as if the message of the fables was “Live, love, laugh!” – which as far as I know is not in fact the case. There seems to have been a school of thought that read *vita* as “those living,” i.e., the writer's contemporaries, yielding the translation: “to teach society with prudent counsel.” This is actually not completely crazy, as this meaning is also attested in other (poetic) contexts (see Lewis & Short). Still, it seems not to have gained much traction.

Comment: *Dos* might primarily mean 'dowry', but the idea that that meaning is older than the meaning 'gift' is pretty silly.

Comment: Is **quod** of indirect speech and an object clause interchangeable (**calumniari arbores loqui**)?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Which definition of **quod** in L&S matches the **quod** (with **calumniari**) here? I can't find a matching entry in Allen & Greenough's, either.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Well, if you put it like that ... but L&S are referring to "gift" in a translated sense, i.e. "talent, advantageous property" &c. Incidentally, the English term "endowed" has come to be used almost exclusively in this sense ;-)

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian This is a completely normal causal *quod* like you've seen a hundred times before, meaning “because.” *Calumniari* is not the verbum dicendi; in fact, there isn't any. If you want, you can imagine something like: *Calumniari si quis autem voluerit, dicens id se facere quod [vel quia] arbores loquantur &c.* That should make clear why you see the subjunctive, but note that it is different from what is actually written – no explicit mention of a causal relationship is put in the critics' mouths by the author.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a partial answer to the OP's question and a follow-up commentary on Sebastian's correct answer to what he refers to as the "difficult question".

In my opinion, what is really "puzzling" is not the syntax nor the interpretation of the Latin text but rather Ørberg's misleading note/equation *prudenti vitam monere* = *prudentem de vitā monere*. Here it is just the case that the surface syntax of the original text does not express two **elliptical** constituents that are indeed relevant for the interpretation: cf. the predicative frames ***alicui** risum movere* (cf. the explicit dative *mihi* in this example from Cicero: *Ille* mihi risum *magis quam stomachum* movere *solet* (Cic. *Att.* 6,3,7)) and ***aliquem** vitam  monere* (*prudenti consilio*). I agree with Kingshorsey's comment above that *prudenti* goes with the nominal adjunct *consilio*, which acts as an instrumental modifier of *monet*.

Given the normal (i.e. unpuzzling!) ellipsis of the dative animate argument with *risum movet* in the first conjunct, one wonders why the ellipsis of the accusative animate argument of *monet* in the second conjunct should instead be considered as "puzzling". These two animate arguments are *both* expected to be elliptical here since we are dealing with a generic context. To conclude, the alleged "puzzle", "riddle" or whatever is in our heads but not in the Latin text.

Comment: If that is how you read the passage (and I am inclined to agree), then Ørberg's explanation is not simply misleading, but wrong. A Google Books search will soon reveal, however, that widely varying interpretations existed long before Ørberg came along. It's a good question why, though, since as you say there is nothing special about *monere* without an explicit recipient.

Answer (score -2):

*dos, dotis* 3f is a word meaning a dowry. For example, in the *Ars Amatoria* there is a sentence: *dos est uxoria lites* ("the dowry of a wife is quarreling").

Why does *prudenti* seem dative? To me it seems to be an adjective in the ablative modifying and agreeing with *consilio*, "(it) counsels life **by prudent advice**".

The word *loquantur* is in the subjunctive because it is in a subordinate clause, and moreover it is a causal subordinate clause. There is an [article in the Dickinson web site that discusses how to undersand the subjunctive with respect to causal clauses.](https://classics.osu.edu/Undergraduate-Studies/Latin-Program/Grammar/indirect-discourse/subordinate-clauses) When subordinate ideas are hypothetical or causal, then they are almost always subjunctive. So, for example, if you have a sentence like "If X happens to be true **(because Y causes this)**, then blah blah." The causal clause will be in the subjunctive, as it is here.

*quod* does mean "because" here but that does not necessarily require the indicative.